# Jenkins declarative pipeline: Sequential execution of an axis of a matrix-build

Tags: jenkins, matrix, jenkins-pipeline, declarative

I am trying to set up a matrix build and am running in several issues.
The matrix looks like:

```
stage( 'BuildAll' ) {
    matrix {
        axes {
            axis {
                name 'PLATFORM'
                values 'win32vc9', 'win32vc19' 
            }                   
            axis {
                name 'VARIANT'
                values 'debug', 'release'                   
            }
            axis {
                name 'MODULES'
                values 'repo1/module1', 'repo1/module2', 'repo2/module1', 'repo2/module2'
            }
        }

        stages {                                                
            stage( 'Checkout' ) {
            }
            stage( 'Build' ) {
            }
            stage( 'Test' ) {
            }
       }
```

The issue I have:

- jenkins is executing every cell of the matrix in it's own workspace but my modules depend on each other. That's why I want do check them out and build them in the same workspace. BTW: my build system is made to work with all the variants (debug/release x vc9/vc19) in the same workspace.
- jenkins is executing all the cells in parallel. What I need, is a serialization of execution of the MODULES axis.

Any ideas how I can work around this?

E.g. is there a way to descripe something like a loop over several modules that generates a sequence of stages in a row, not parallel? Within that sequence I could realize the matrix over 2 axes only.

I am aware of extended workspace plugin but did not find any documentation of how to use this in declarative pipelines.

Many thanks in advance!
Regards,
Christoph

Comment: I have the same problem: I have 2 axis and I want to run first all cells for 1st entry of the axis and after they are completed I want to run all cells for the 2nd entry in the axis. But I don't see that this is possible

Comment: I have this problem and i do not find any good solution.

Answer (score 6):

You might be able to do what you want by using [locks](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/).

In my case, I just wanted the matrix to build sequentially instead of in parallel, so I just wrapped everything in a stage and put a lock on it. Something like:

```
stage( 'BuildAll' ) {
    matrix {
        axes {
            ...
        }
        stages {                                                
            stage( 'Sequential Matrix' ) {
                options {
                    lock( 'synchronous-matrix' )
                }
                stages {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only one matrix configuration can build at a time since the others can't acquire the lock until the current config is done.

In your case though, you want the modules to build one after the other *in order*.
The string for the lock resource can be dynamic, so you can use a name constructed from the other 2 axes to prevent multiple modules from building at the same time:

```
stage( 'BuildAll' ) {
    matrix {
        axes {
            axis {
                name 'PLATFORM'
                values 'win32vc9', 'win32vc19' 
            }                   
            axis {
                name 'VARIANT'
                values 'debug', 'release'                   
            }
            axis {
                name 'MODULES'
                values 'repo1/module1', 'repo1/module2', 'repo2/module1', 'repo2/module2'
            }
        }

        stages {                                                
            stage( 'Force Sequential' ) {
                options {
                    lock( "synchronous-${PLATFORM}-${VARIANT}" )
                }
                stages {
                    stage( 'Checkout' ) {

                    }
                    stage( 'Build' ) {

                    }
                    stage( 'Test' ) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this would only guarantee modules of the same platform and variant don't build at the same time and doesn't say anything about ordering. I don't know if the order which Jenkins chooses to build axes is defined, but I found [matrix-sorter-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/Matrix-sorter-plugin) which may help with ordering if it's an issue.

Comment: I like this approach a lot because I'm trying to have the matrix run parallel builds per PLATFORM only.
However, I'm getting this error when I put a lock on PLATFORM is: "no such property PLATFORM" and when I remove the lock it just works in full parallel mode. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, late response, but if it's still relevant, could you share the code?

Answer (score 5):

I used `for` loop instead of `matrix` and `axis` syntax.  My workaround is not as pretty as using `matrix` syntax, but it does what it supposed to do.

```
String[] platformList = ['win32vc9', 'win32vc19']
String[] variantList = ['debug', 'release']

pipeline{
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Deploy'){
            steps{
                script{
                    for(platform in platformList){
                        for(variant in variantList){
                            stage("Checkout"){
                                powershell label: '', script: """Write-Output Step1 "${platform}/${variant}/Checkout" """
                            }
                            stage("Build"){
                                powershell label: '', script: """Write-Output Step1 "${platform}/${variant}/Build" """
                            }
                            stage("Test"){
                                powershell label: '', script: """Write-Output Step1 "${platform}/${variant}/Test" """
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declarative Pipeline `matrix` directive doesn't currently support sequential execution.
The best you can do in in the current `matrix` syntax is this:

```
 stage( 'BuildAll' ) {
    matrix {
        axes {
            axis {
                name 'PLATFORM'
                values 'win32vc9', 'win32vc19' 
            }                   
            axis {
                name 'VARIANT'
                values 'debug', 'release'                   
            }
        }
        stages {                
            stage('repo1/module1') {
                stages {
                    stage( 'Checkout' ) {
                    }
                    stage( 'Build' ) {
                    }
                    stage( 'Test' ) {
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('repo1/module2') {
                stages {
                    stage( 'Checkout' ) {
                    }
                    stage( 'Build' ) {
                    }
                    stage( 'Test' ) {
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('repo2/module1') {
                stages {
                    stage( 'Checkout' ) {
                    }
                    stage( 'Build' ) {
                    }
                    stage( 'Test' ) {
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('repo2/module2') {
                stages {
                    stage( 'Checkout' ) {
                    }
                    stage( 'Build' ) {
                    }
                    stage( 'Test' ) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Others have asked for similar.  I've filed [JENKINS-62085](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-62085) based on this question.