# How to create separate workspace for different matrix axis build in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

```
def job_name = env.JOB_NAME

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            matrix {
                agent {
                    node {
                        label 'BuildAndTest_Ubuntu1604' 
                        customWorkspace 'workspace/${job_name}/${BUILD}'
                    }
                }
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'BUILD'
                        values 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
                    }
                }
                when {
                    beforeAgent true
                    anyOf {
                        branch 'master'
                        branch 'develop'
                        branch pattern: '^release/.*', comparator: 'REGEXP'
                        equals expected: singleVariant, actual: env.BUILD
                        expression { return buildAllVariants }
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Build, Sign and Upload Bundle') {
                        steps {
                            script {
                                ...
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I tried the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67193613) to get the `customWorkspace` for each different matrix axis build.

However, when Jenkins compiles, it does not translate the `${job_name}/${BUILD}` correctly. In fact, it just creates 2 folders in the workspace:

1. A folder called `${job_name}`
2. Another folder called "project" namespace

The Jenkins build fails when it tries to clone the repo with an error message:

> stderr: fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Can any Jenkinsfile expert show where are the mistakes & how to fix them?

Thanks

Comment: If the matrix computes 5 stages, Do you need 5 different folder locations to perform some operations on each one?

Comment: @JRichardsz, each matrix axis will use the same folder location to complete 5 stages

Comment: You can try to avoid the customWorkspace, and instead run your `steps` inside a `dir("${BUILD}")` directive - thus causing each axis to run in its own folder